# Iterate over through column while creating new column matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, iterator

I have a small dataset and would like to construct a iterative loop that allows me to run through one column (loops are more intuitive for me at this stage) and use to results to construct a new column in the same table.

My `tallard.txt` file:

```
Date - precipitation
1/1/2012 - 4
1/2/2012 - 1
1/3/2012 - 3
1/4/2012 - 0
1/5/2012 - 1
1/6/2012 - 0
```

I need to add up the daily precipitation and assign in to the median date, this allows me to determine the amount of precipitation for rain events (multiple days) so the proposed column ends up like this:

```
Date - precipitation
1/1/2012 - 4 - NaN  % or 0
1/2/2012 - 1 - 8    % (4+3+1)
1/3/2012 - 3 - NaN  % or 0 or original value if that's easier
1/4/2012 - 0 - 0
1/5/2012 - 1 - 1
1/6/2012 - 0 - 0
```

This is what I campe up so far:

```
clear all
load tallard.txt;
X = 2;  % columns
Y = 11416;  % rows
counter = 2;

for i = 1:Y
    if tallard(counter, 2) >= 1
        tallard(counter:Y,2) = tallard(counter,2)+ tallard(counter-1,6);
    else
        tallard(counter:Y,2) = tallard(counter,2);
    end
    counter = counter+1;
end
```

But this only works for 2 consecutive precipitation days, as soon this is 3 days or more this doesn't hold up. The dataset contains 11000 days.

Comment: What does "this doesn't hold up" mean?

Comment: It means that as soon there is more than 2 precipitation days the result will be not as I would like to have it. In my example it will result in:
1/1/2012 - 4 - 4
1/2/2012 - 1 - 5 (4+3+1)
1/3/2012 - 3 - 4 
1/4/2012 - 0 - 0
1/5/2012 - 1 - 1
1/6/2012 - 0 - 0

I would like to see the 0 as breaks in rain events.

Comment: You need to [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) where the precipitation is `0` and use those indices to construct your intervals.

Comment: Ok Thanks I will have a go at it, not sure yet how to construct intervals out of these indices tough.

Comment: Haven't been able to figure out how to construct the intervals and link those to the original table to add up successive raind events. Have tried to look up  information about the find function but I believe i'm stuck at the moment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. But here is something that I think you want.

```
windowSz = 3;
h = ones(windowSz, 1);
tallard(:, 3) = filter(h, 1, tallard(:, 2));
```

Comment: This only seems to work for windowsize three, unfortuanately the dataset has 11000 records, so often precipitation is 0 for more than 3 days. 
I like to add up all the succesive raindays to 1 event and repeat that for all rain events (precipitation > 0)